# In Swift&Objc mixed app Xcode cannot find protocol for Realm to-many relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, realm

For some reason I need to have some objc code in my project but all the new code is being written in Swift. And I am starting to add Realm into the project. Since RealmSwift cannot be used in a mixed application so I need to go with Realm Objective-C.

So I defined my two models: item and appraisal like this:

```
@interface Item : RLMObject

@property NSString *name;
@property NSString *upc;
@property Appraisal *appraisal;

@end
RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(Item)

@interface Appraisal : NSObject

@property NSString *name;
@property RLMArray<Item> *items;

@end
```

I need to use these models in my new Swift code so i put them in the bridging-header file. like this:

```
#import "Item.h"
#import "Appraisal.h"
```

As long as I have them in the bridging-heder I cannot compile the code because of the error "Cannot find protocol declaration for "item"".

Anybody seen this before and had a solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This may be a long shot, but in which header file is the line `RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(Item)` located in?

Answer (score 0):

Since your error message is `Cannot find protocol declaration for "item"`, it is possible you wrote `RLMArray<item>` instead of `RLMArray<Item>` ?